# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1), on a dictionary

Tags: dictionary, machine-learning, iterator, svm, logistic-regression

I tried searching for the answer, but I dont know why it is expecting 4...so I can't find the solution. I am trying to make a script that will iterate over the models and then create a plot based on their performance with regards to the iris dataset and the feature scalings I applied. currently this is the segment of the code in which I am getting the error.

Code:

```
models = {
    "Logistic Regression": LogisticRegression(),
    "Decision Tree": DecisionTreeClassifier(max_leaf_nodes=3),
    "Random Forest": RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=3),
    "svm_model" : SVC(kernel='linear')
}

def evaluate_model(model, dataset):
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = data
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    pred = model.predict(x_test)
    return accuracy_score(pred, y_test)

for model_name, model in models.items():
        model_score = evaluate_model(model, dataset)
        #dataset_scores[model_name] = model_score
        
       # model_scores_for_datasets[dataset_name] = dataset_scores
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-531-35544d14a669> in <module>
      7 
      8 for model_name, model in models.items():
----> 9         model_score = evaluate_model(model, dataset)
     10         #dataset_scores[model_name] = model_score
     11 

<ipython-input-521-f26300591060> in evaluate_model(model, dataset)
     13 
     14 def evaluate_model(model, dataset):
---> 15     x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = data
     16     model.fit(x_train, y_train)
     17     pred = model.predict(x_test)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, it is not clear what the type or shape of your *data* variable is. Did you properly split your data so that you will return test and train splits?

For example let's say you have some paired data:

```py
x = np.arange(1, 25).reshape(12, 2)
y = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

You need to use train_test_split from sklearn to split it as:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y)
```

But your *data* variable includes only one iterable item, so fails to unpack it into 4 variables *x_train*, *x_test*, *y_train* and *y_test*. You may basically generate the same error as:

```py
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = [1]
```

Also your *evaluate_model* function does not use the *dataset* input, but uses a global *data* to unpack. Thus replace that line to make the function work as it was intended.

```py
def evaluate_model(model, dataset):
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = dataset
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    pred = model.predict(x_test)
    return accuracy_score(pred, y_test)
```

Comment: Yes my data is split, properly. y_train and y test are arrays that  look like this: array([0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0,
       2, 0, 1, 2, 2, and x_train, and x_test are data frames. x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42,stratify=y) is what I used.

Comment: Still, the issue is with the _data_ variable. Check its type and size with:
`m = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42, stratify=y)`
`print(type(m), len(m))`
and see what you have in data.

Comment: <class 'list'> 4 this is the output with that

Comment: @FrancescaC also you get the parameter _dataset_ in your _evaluate_model_ function but assign _data_ to splits. I guess that is the issue.

Comment: Hmmm, let me add the rest of the code to see if that still applies

Comment: Yes, that still applies. You are not using the function parameter, but rather a global data variable

Comment: Hmm I am confused, what does the data being assigned to splits have anything to do with the argument for the function?

Comment: Basically, you aim to create a function that evaluates your input _dataset_ for a given input model. But then in the function, you are not using that input data which is _dataset_, rather a global _data_ variable that you have previously created and assigned somewhere in your notebook. Thus your function will not give the result over your input anyways. That is something you should fix. But in addition, you should consider what @Pathi_rao says about turning your datasets into NumPy arrays. Now you don't the error about it, because you are not using the correct input in evaluate function.

Comment: Ah...I have not got the data variable in my notebook, I didn't know it needed to be assigned to something, what should it be assigned to then? and in what format? thanks for the clear explanations!! very helpful. my data is assigned to iris...I will put iris instead

Comment: That seems to do something, I got: 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'SepalLengthCm', which means they aren't all in bumpy arrays... maybe?

Comment: Alright, I fixed it, here is the next error `-input-647-d3990822e48c> in <module>
     25 
     26     for model_name, model in models.items():
---> 27         model_score = evaluate_model(model, dataset)
     28         dataset_scores[model_name] = model_score
     29 

<ipython-input-647-d3990822e48c> in evaluate_model(model, dataset)
     13 
     14 def evaluate_model(model, dataset):
---> 15     x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = iris
     16     model.fit(x_train, y_train)
     17     pred = model.predict(x_test)

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable method object `

Comment: Do not assign something new to data, instead change the _data_ in your _evaluate_model_ function to _dataset_ as `x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = dataset`. Otherwise, writing such a function does not make sense. Then if your splits are correct and NumPy arrays, it should work without an issue. Do not give iris, use _dataset_ there which is already your function parameter.

Comment: I think it works! I don't get any error code! no idea if it worked though, need to graph it

Comment: Yup, you just made an error in the function by not using the parameter you got. You may read more on how functions work to learn more. I have also edited the original answer by adding that part. Please also delete your notebook photo and full script which you have posted as answers, it makes everything confusing :) You may add them to your original question by editing instead if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

The `ValueError` is raised because you are trying to unpack more values than the total that exists in the `data` variable. So, in your case, the error is telling us that there is only one value inside the `data` but you are trying to unpack four.

Make sure you have four values inside the `data` variable to unpack.

It's not possible to answer exactly as we don't know what's inside the `data` variable. One possible example is how you split the data in `sklearn`.

```py
from sklearn import model_selection

x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

Edit1: adding a code snippet that you can reference

```py
# imports
from sklearn import datasets

iris_data = datasets.load_iris() # get the iris data directly from sklearn

#put the dataset into a pandas DF using the feature names as columnsç
#rename the column name so they don't include the '(cm)'
#add 2 columns one with the target and another with the target_names 
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset['data'], columns=dataset['feature_names'])
df.columns = ['sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width']
df['target'] = dataset['target']
df['class'] = dataset.target_names[dataset.target]

dummy = pd.get_dummies(df_iris, columns=["target"])

X = df_iris[['sepal length','sepal width']].to_numpy() #only selects specified column and converts to numpy arrays
Y = df_iris.target.to_numpy() # target to numpy 

#Split the data into train and test
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, train_size = 0.8, random_state = 42)

#normalize the dataset
#create and fit the scaler object on the training data
# do the training
```

Comment: yes but I print each of my test and train, and indeed they each are split. I will add a screenshot from the output now

Comment: One more thing to point out is your variable `Xtest`. The values that you pass to a model should be NumPy arrays and not a dataframe.  Example,

`X = df_iris[['sepal length', 'sepal width']].values
print(X.shape)`

Comment: should I use df.to_numpy()?

Comment: num_x_test= x_test.to_numpy()
num_x_test and OUTPUT: array([[4.4, 3. , 1.3, 0.2],
       [6.1, 3. , 4.9, 1.8],
       [4.9, 2.4, 3.3, 1. ],
       [5. , 2.3, 3.3, 1. ],
       [4.4, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],

Comment: 1. Please don't post your pictures as answers to the question, instead add them to the original question to keep things tidy.

2. I can nowhere see the `data` variable in the pictures that you posted. Keep things relevant so that we can help you quickly

3. You should transform your **entire** data into NumPy arrays. `model_selection.train_test_split(X, y)`. You can directly do the conversion to the variables `X`, `y`

Comment: Okay I will transform all and see. but for the data variable, where should that be? I thought it should only be in the script as its being assigned to that..  indeed when I print data it is: `[Bar({
     'marker': {'color': ['#E4ACEC', '#9C1779', '#242B58']},
     'x': array(['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica'], dtype=object),
     'y': array([50, 50, 50])
 })]`

Comment: I am not sure what my data variable should be outside the script itself, you are saying it should be assigned already? I transformed the X variable as it was in a df, y is already an array.

Comment: I think you are confusing "assigning a variable to some data" and "unpacking data to some variables". These two have completely different purpose. Since this question is going off in a tangent, I would either suggest to read the Sklearn documentation. If you are still facing the issue, post your notebook. Its not possible to answer every small thing in comments when we and *you* don't know how your script is written

Comment: Okay, I have converted all to numpy and fixed the data variable, but it is now saying: `---> 15     x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = iris
     16     model.fit(x_train, y_train)
     17     pred = model.predict(x_test)

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable method object
`
Why would it be equal to none type? it needs to be a list or a tuple to unpack?

Comment: `x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = iris` this is what's wrong. this is called unpacking. You cannot unpack the dataset directly into some variables unless that operation exists. Nevertheless, I will update my answer and add a code snippet that you can work out.